# Why unzipFile method of minizip return false?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I used minizip framework for my project (Xcode 7.2) and it extracted zip files correctly. So now I convert my project to Xcode 8.2.1 but unzipFile method of minizip always return false!

Header file:

```
#import "ZipArchive.h"
```

This is my function:

```
func extract(Source: String , Destination : String) -> Bool{
    return Main.unzipFile(atPath: Source, toDestination: Destination)

}
```

[This is minizip framework files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZf4s.png)

Comment: SSZipArchive returns false when it cant find the zip file. what is your paths ?

Comment: I checked directory of my iPad . Zip file exist. 
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/06209A63-B945-4656-B4AE-E00275FB2725/Documents/tmpNYH/20170403_062519_1491200719_565.zip

and this is destination path:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/06209A63-B945-4656-B4AE-E00275FB2725/Documents/tmpNYH

Comment: Can't you check the errno? Alternatively, switch to a packaged version of Minizip, like this one: https://github.com/dexman/Minizip